# Retornar data JSON no HTML

Tags: javascript, json

Pessoa, preciso de ajuda com uma chamada de uma API, que retorna um JSON.

Já tentei diversas coisas, mas não consigo fazer com que retorne no meu HTML as informações.

Alguém consegue me apoiar com algum código? Não coloquei aqui o que usei pois utilizei vários.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só preciso pegar o name e o description. Já usei o name direto, usei values.name, mas nada funcionou.

Um exemplo do meu javascript

```js
var pageCounter = 1;
var animalContainer = document.getElementById("animal-info");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ourRequest.open('GET', '');
  ourRequest.onload = function() {
    if (ourRequest.status >= 200 && ourRequest.status < 400) {
      var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
      renderHTML(ourData);
    } else {
      console.log("We connected to the server, but it returned an error.");
    }    
  };
  ourRequest.onerror = function() {
    console.log("Connection error");
  };
  ourRequest.send();
  pageCounter++;
  if (pageCounter > 10) {
    btn.classList.add("hide-me");
  }
});
function renderHTML(data) {
  var htmlString = "";

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    htmlString += "<p>" + data.values[i].name + data.values[i].description;

    htmlString += '.</p>';

  }

  animalContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>JSON and AJAX</h1>
    <button id="btn">Fetch Info for 3 New Animals</button>
  </header>
  
  <div id="animal-info"></div>

  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Obrigado.

Comment: se está usando `data.values[i].name` no for deveria ser `data.values.length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como mencionado pelo @RicardoPontual no comentário, o problema muito provavelmente se encontra no seguinte bloco de código:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    htmlString += "<p>" + data.values[i].name + data.values[i].description;

    htmlString += '.</p>';

  }
```

Você está verificando `data.length`. Se instanciar um objeto e tentar encontrar uma propriedade `length` dele (a não ser que tenha sido explicitamente declarada) retornará `undefined`. Nesse caso, seu laço de repetição não chega a executar.

Sendo isso mesmo, o que corrige o problema:

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.values.length; i++) {
    htmlString += "<p>" + data.values[i].name + data.values[i].description;

    htmlString += '.</p>';

}
```

Verifique a propriedade `length` (tamanho) da propriedade `values` e não do objeto `data` que é seu JSON convertido a partir do `JSON.parse`. O `length` da propriedade `values` retornará o tamanho da lista.

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.

Comment: Ruan, obrigado. Era exatamente isso que vocês citaram.

O meu problema agora é conseguir jogar a informação para uma tabela. Está aparecendo tudo na mesma linha.

Comment: Estou tendo retorno de undefined no campo description

Answer (score 0):

Estou tendo retorno de undefined no campo description

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mudei o .js. Não estava conseguindo evoluir com aquele.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button-buscar-licencas-ambiente").click(function(){
    var urlapi = '';
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", urlapi, false);
    xhttp.send();
    var obj = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
    var data_map = new Map();
    var index = 0;
      var objLength = obj.values.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < objLength; i++) {
            data_map.set(obj.values[i].name, data_map.get(obj.values[i].name) + obj.values[i].description);
        }
    const objConverted = Object.fromEntries(data_map);      
    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(objConverted); 
    data_map.forEach(montaTabelaLicencas);
    event.preventDefault();  
  });
});



function montaTabelaLicencas(licencasConsumidas, hostGroup) {

  var newRow = $('<tr class="linha-table">');
      var cols = "";

        cols += '<td class="hostgroup" id="hostgroup">' + hostGroup + '</td>';
        cols += '<td class="quantidade" id="quantidade">' + licencasConsumidas + '</td>';

      newRow.append(cols);

       $("#table-licencas").append(newRow); 
        
};
```

Comment: Tente não colocar outras perguntas como resposta de uma pergunta anterior, creio que seja melhor fazer outra. Dito isso, acredito que o problema esteja no `for`, dado que está chamando o `get` do seu `Map` com a chave do valor que está configurando durante a chamada do `set`. Como ele ainda não existe, retorna `undefined`.

Sendo esse o caso, o correto seria dentro do for: `data_map.set(obj.values[i].name, obj.values[i].name + obj.values[i].description);`.

Comment: Obrigado Ruan!!